# Delete all folders except 2 latest folders in Windows

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I want to delete all the folders from a directory except the 2 most recently updated folders (Last modified date).

I want to do this using the command line. How do I do it?

Below is the code to display folders sorted by last modified time:

```
dir /ad-h /od
```

I tried using `FOR /D` command:

```
for /d "skip=2 tokens=*" %G in ("dir /ad-h /od") DO echo going to delete %G
```

But I get the below error message:

```
"skip=2 tokens=*" was unexpected at this time.
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f "skip=2 delims=" %G in ('dir /B /ad-h /o-d "d:\your path" ') DO echo going to delete "%G"
```

`For /f` to process lines of "output" from `single-quoted` DIR...

`Delims=` is better. `tokens=*` will work here, but suppresses leading spaces.

`/b` to suppress header output from `dir`

`/o-d` for REVERSE-date order. You want to KEEP the two skipped dirs, which occur FIRS in a reverse-date sort.

...good `echo` safety measure.

Comment: in `/ad-h` /ad selects only directories and the -h removes hidden folders from the list.

Comment: @Magoo You might just have saved me from more headaches. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796149/windows-batch-script-to-only-keep-the-n-latest-folders-in-a-directory and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31787056/windows-batch-script-to-backup-local-mysql-databases-only-keep-n-latest-folder . Besides this I read your profile and like to reach out to you personally NOT related to IT but to what you write in your profile. Bottom line: So true it hurts and makes me angry. It's not even IT, it is the incompetent HR puppets that ruin everything. Any ways. How can I talk 2 you?

Comment: @Magoo and yes indeed it works, see linked questions with my answers now, though I am changing `del` to `rd` to also delete the folders **with** they contents.

Comment: Where to specify path ?

Comment: @Paul: Fixed. Note use of rabbit's ears to allow spaces in pathname to be correctly processed